# virtualenv install a package that exists globally?

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I set up a VirtualEnvironment. Using the `which` command, I am sure that python 3.5 and pip 9.0.1 which is from Python3.5 are in the local virtualenv. My global system has pip2.7 installed.

I have a git clone that uses python2 and the Tensorflow library. I use pip3 to install tensorflow 1.0.0. Running on python2.7 I get no module named Tensorflow. Executing with python3.5 trips because the project was written in 2.

**What am I trying to do**: install pip2.7 in my virtualenv (instead of my global MacOS, which it is currently under), and then I can use to install Tensorflow (python 2.7) aka this:

```
# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
(tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

If I install it with pip3.5 (virtualenv) I get: `tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

If I install it with pip2.7 (MacOS Global), one of the global dependencies, Numpy, throws an exception and it won't install Tensorflow.

**All I need to do is get pip2.7 on virtualenv.** Attempts like `pip install pip2.7` while in the virtualenv fail as it says `No matching distribution found for pip2.7`. As you know, virtualenv's `-no-site-packages` has been made the default so that's not the issue.

I've tried some other answers, like --upgrade which produces `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip2.7`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually to make a new virtualenv, this time with Python2.7

`virtualenv -p python2.7 ~/my/env/dir/`

pip2.7 and python2.7 were installed and I could install Tensorflow beautifully!